# New to Access How to run VBA code that doesn't have Sub?

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image: VBA IDE Window]

Hi, I'm new to Access and I have a quick question. 
I have a code that does not have 'sub'. And I was wondering how can I execute my code when I don't see any on Macro window? (Refer to the image attached)

My code start with function and declaration of variables!

It's very straight forward question but please comment below for any clarification if needed!

Comment: What you have is a `Function`, you cant just launch it, because it needs parameters. Write your own sub (without parameters) that launches the function, feeding it with the right parameters and handling its result.

Comment: @A.S.H. So you mean like Sub myownsub() on the first line?

Comment: `Sub myownsub()` you can write the sub anywhere, outside the body of the function of course.

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you!! It does work!

Comment: @A.S.H Functions don't need parameters. Functions return something (`x = FunctionName()`). Sub returns nothing (`SubName`). Both may or may not have parameters (`x = FunctionName(Param)` and `SubName Param`). Subs are called without brackets (`SubName`). Functions are called with brackets (`ret = FunctionName()`). You can also call a function as a sub without brackets (`FunctionName`) and the return is discarded.

Comment: @Noodles The function that the OP wants to launch has (non-optional) parameters.

Comment: That's not the point. You incorrectly described the difference between a sub and function.

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to run a function with the press of a button for example, you must:

a) Put the function in a standard module, within the vba editor. Move the code to a new module and then call the function from a macro.

Or

b) Run the function from within an event vba sub like the click of button.

[image: Like This]

Answer (score 0):

For both a sub, and a function in a code module, you can normally place the cursor in the sub/function and hit F5, and the code will run.

The above works for both a sub and function.

However, WHEN the sub/function has a parameter(s), then the F5 option will not work. In your screen shot the given function requires a parameter, so the long standing F5 to run such code as per above will not work. What occurs in this case is the macro prompt will launch as you point out.

Two suggestions:
Whack ctrl-g and your cursor should now be in the debug window, you can type in the name of the function (or sub) and SUPPLY the parameter.

Eg:

```
Test9999 "my first prameter"
```

The other means is to write a test code stub that passes the parmaters like this:

```
Public Sub RunMyFunction()

   Test8888 "my paramter"

End Sub
```

And thus you can now hit F5. So you don’t need to run the code from a form or a button as suggested here. However, the instant the sub/function has a parameter(s), then you lose the F5 to run the code from the VBA IDE. You have to write a code stub, or as noted enter the function name + supply the required parameters of the correct type in the debug window to run the function.

However, to be fair, you can build a test form, and place code behind a button, but your question was in the context of the IDE and use of F5 to run such code.